# Touches in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've got a view of size 320x480 and in it an UIScrollView that takes all the place in my view.

The scroll view can scroll only in horizontal direction and I want to implement my own method for handling vertical swipes.

UIScrollView seems not to respond to touchesBegan and to touchesMoved.

What is the solution to my problem?

How can I get touches that were made on UIScrollView?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say does not respond to touchesBegan and touchesMoved, what do you mean? I've been able to override these in a subclass to do single-tap detection.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're trying? UIScrollView inherits from UIView, so it should respond to `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` just like any other view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, but I think I know what is happening. `UIScrollView` is built for getting coordinates relative to its content, which it tries to follow. So the coordinates are different, that's my guess. I tried to also forward touch events to the scrollview's gesture recognizers. I got some response, but not by far as smooth as if the `UIScrollView` would be handling the touches directly.

EDIT:

I finally found out how to work around the difference between the `UITouch` objects delivered (or whatever is causing trouble when throwing them around). I did override `hitTest:withEvent`  to change which `UIView` handled certain touches.